# PHP link with a variable

Tags: php, hyperlink

Small question. I take the link address from DB to $lnk. then I want to show the link. all within PHP code. Problem is, my source page address is added in the link (if my current page is www.abc.com and $lnk= 123.com,  then the page open from the link as www.abc.com/www.123com ) 
I just want to open www.123.com once user click on "Web Link" (preferebly in a new window :) )

```
$slCoEx = "SELECT * FROM Corporate_Extra WHERE ID =".$info['ID'];     
$dataEx = mysql_query($slCoEx) or die(mysql_error());        
$infoEx = mysql_fetch_array($dataEx);     
$lnk    = $infoEx['www'];  
echo "<a href=$lnk>Web Link</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Add `http://` protocol infront of your link

```
echo "<a href=http://$lnk  target='_blank'>Web Link</a>";
```

Comment: Answer came even before I tried to edit the post :) Thanks Krish R